# Add item to listbox from another form

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to add items to listbox from another form but the listbox doesn't seem to update.

I have 3 form : frm1, frm2, frm3

this my code in frm1 to open frm2:

```vb
Using frm As New frm2
    frm.ShowDialog()
End Using
```

frm2 has a listbox named list_xxx

code in frm3:

```vb
Private Sub add_item()
    frm2.list_xxx.add("aaaa")
End Sub
```

i want to add item to frm2 from frm3. but no success the listbox still empty.
how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost certainly referring to the default instance of `frm2` in that second code snippet but you aren't displaying the default instance in the first code snippet. If you display one form and then add items to a `ListBox` on another form, there should be no surprise that you can't see those items. Either use the default instance everywhere or not at all. The more correct option is not at all, but that would require other changes too. The easier option is everywhere, which means changing the first code snippet to this:

```vb
frm2.ShowDialog()
```

No `Using` statement because you're not creating an object.

Comment: @DhadanMrd, FYI, this site frowns on comments like that. The site is supposed to be about information only. Accepting the question as you have is all the thanks required. Don't feel like you're being rude not saying it explicitly.